# What is the difference between declaring variable in for loop and an outside loop?

Tags: javascript

I searched for this question but the answers I got not solve my question . Here is my question , I have a array with 10 members .

**Js Code**

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

**Loop 1:**

```
for(var i=0,len=array.length;i<len;i++){};
```

**Loop 2**

```
var len = array.length;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){};
```

**Loop 3**

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){}
```

I know there is a major performance difference between 1 and 3 . But , is there any performance difference between 1 and 2 ? .

Comment: Why don't you test it for your self? =)

Comment: There is no difference between 1 and 2 except you've just written an extra line in loop 2, where you have'nt in loop 3

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope for lots of information about JavaScript variable scope.

Comment: With older browsers you would see a speed boost with _loop1_ or _loop2_, but with modern day browsers it does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any noticeable difference, although the parsing logic has one more token to parse in example 2.

Shorter is better: `var a,b,c,d;` should be faster than

```
var a; var b; var c; var d;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any difference. Javascript will hoist variables.

So code1 will be:

```
var i, len;
for (i=0, len=array.lengh; i<len; i++) {};
```

code2 will be

```
var i, len;
len = array.lengh;
for (i=0; i<len; i++) {};
```

The difference is only where to put the `len=array.length`

Answer (score 0):

Loop-1 and Loop-2 both are same because of there is one time Initialize of var len
so no difference in performance .

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has function scope, not block scope (excluding the new `let` syntax). Since a for loop is not a function it does not create a new scope, which means

```
for (var i...) { ... }
```

is exactly the same as

```
var i...
for (...) { ... }
```

However, the conditional statement of a for loop is re-evaluated every iteration in javascript, meaning this

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){}
```

will need to evaluate `array.length` many times, whereas this

```
var len = array.length;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){};
```

once evaluates it once. It is faster, theoretically, but it is such a micro-optimization that it does not really matter.